# Facebook Graph API Timeout

Tags: asp.net, facebook-graph-api

I've a Canva app built in C# .NET. To request the Graph API, I use the Facebook C# SDK (https://github.com/facebook/csharp-sdk).

We updated it with the following request modifications:

```
request.KeepAlive = false;
request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;
request.Timeout = 1000 * 30;
```

Sometimes, the requests are very fast (**~1.5s**), but sometimes (very often), the same request from the same server take **more than 30s** (response time got with Wireshark).

Note that my requests are pretty simple ("/[user_id]").
Note also that we tried on several platform (from Amazon servers, rackspace, home...) and we got the same results.

Does someone experciences such latency or someone has an idea how to avoid it?

I saw in Graph API documentation that there can be latency, but 30s... it's not what I call a latency :)

Thank you for your help

Comment: Hi JBS, could you explained where in the c# sdk source code you made the modification ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

its a common problem, that the graph api is sometimes very slow,so there is no solution to make the requests faster.

Only little idea is to make batch requests in stead of a lot single requests
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/

Comment: Crap :( Thank you anyway for your help!